# nhibernate configuration multiple databases

Tags: database, nhibernate, configuration

i have this configuration

```
 var config = new Configuration().Configure(path);
                config.AddAssembly(Assembly.GetCallingAssembly());
                _factory = config.BuildSessionFactory();
```

and nhibernate.cfg.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<hibernate-configuration  xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2" >
  <session-factory name="ServiceCenter.DataAccess">
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">
      Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=111;User Id=111;Password=111;
    </property>
    <property name="show_sql">false</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect</property>
    <property name="query.substitutions">true 1, false 0, yes 'Y', no 'N'</property>

  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I want to have 2 connection strings. I try to add second connection string and second 
session-factory in config file, but it was not correct.

Comment: What is your problem exactly? As you said, you need to have to session factories (for each connection to the database).

Comment: Yes, i want have connections to 2 databases, i try to add second section <session-factory> with another name, and  use SetProperty(SessionFactoryName, "correct_factory_name") but then exception occured

Comment: You may look at this nice article by Karl Seguin
http://codebetter.com/karlseguin/2009/03/30/using-nhibernate-with-multiple-databases/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a good extension for this called NHibernate-X-Factories. Have a look at this answer: [Configure NHibernate hibernate.cfg.xml file to have more connection strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450300/configure-nhibernate-hibernate-cfg-xml-file-to-have-more-connection-strings/10645667#10645667)

Answer (score 0):

There is a good material available here [here](http://creative-jar.com/insights/labs/programming/mvc/transferring-data-between-two-databases-with-nhibernate-in-mvc3/)